# Kotlin Jsoup Android async

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup

I can't get Jsoup to work with Kotlin. I can't scrape any website. Here is my function that prints the result:

```
    fun testing(view: TextView?) {

    async(UI) {
        val data: Deferred<String> = bg {
            KotScrape().getWebsite()
        }

        view?.text = data.await()
    }
}
```

And my KotScrape class:

```
class KotScrape{

    fun getWebsite(): String{
        var title = "Test"
        var html = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=se2eWqfkJKzb6QSoo6iQDQ").timeout(5000).get()
        title = html.title()
        return title
    }
}
```

The problem is that my getWebsite() function never returns. I think it's a JSoup problem because if i remove the two lines with jsoup from the function it works fine:

```
class KotScrape{

    fun getWebsite(): String{
        var title = "Test"
        return title
    }
}
```

This is working without any problem. But when i add jsoup, it never returns, like it would be in an infinite loop.

Comment: Have you tried without the timeout? also, have you added the Internet permission to your manifest? and I don't see any place where you handle the IOException that this call could cause.

Comment: I tried without timeout, I have put the timeout just to test (I was thinking that it's just trying to load the page for infinite time). In this example IOException is not handled, however I have another Java class with similar code where it is handled and the same problem appears. I have forgot to add the Internet permission. Let me try, however I'm thinking that I should still get a timeout if there is no internet permission. So after testing, it turns out It was because I've forgotten to request Internet permission. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, remember in Android that anytime you access a network resource such as a web page in your app code, you need the internet permission, this will throw an exception before your code does.